# Max of substring in column

Tags: excel, vba, string, substring, max

Given that I have a column of values in the format

```
01.2020
12.2021
3.2019
02.2020
etc.
```

over a million rows or so, I want a VBA function to find the maximum value of the digits to the left of the period.

Something like

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    Dim max As Long, current As Long
    Dim s As String
    
    With År_2020
        Set r = .Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    For Each c In r
        current = CLng(Left(c, InStr(1, c, ".", vbBinaryCompare) - 1))
        If current > max Then max = current
    Next c
    
    Debug.Print max
End Sub
```

works, but I feel like there ought to be a simpler solution.

Can someone please give some input on whether they can find a simpler solution?

Comment: What type are those values? obviously they are not numeric? Are they text? dates?

Comment: The characters to the left of the period will always be numeric. They are representing dates (month and year), but Excel does not interpret them as dates. @Pᴇʜ

Comment: Why are you creating a VBA function for this? Do you want to avoid a formula per se?

Comment: @JvdV I am using it in a larger macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Formula solution

[image]

- formula in B1: `=VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1))`
- in C1: `=MAX(B:B)`

#### VBA solution

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim LastRow As Long 'find last used row
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim ValuesToConvert() As Variant 'read data into array
ValuesToConvert = ws.Range("A1", "A" & LastRow).Value 'will throw an error if there is only data in A1 but no data below, make sure to cover that case

Dim iVal As Variant
For iVal = LBound(ValuesToConvert) To UBound(ValuesToConvert)
    'truncate after period (might need some error tests if period does not exist or cell is empty)
    ValuesToConvert(iVal, 1) = CLng(Left(ValuesToConvert(iVal, 1), InStr(1, ValuesToConvert(iVal, 1), ".") - 1))
Next iVal

'get maximum of array values
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ValuesToConvert)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried something similar to your VBA solution, but for some reason the column wouldn't assign to my variant - I think I may have forgotten the parantheses or something :-p

Answer (score 1):

I always like to propose a naive solution. On the face of it you could do this:

```
=TRUNC(MAX(--D:D))
```

(leave the truncation till the end because the part of the number after the decimal point doesn't affect the result)

As pointed out below, this only works correctly for those locales that use a decimal point (period) not a decimal comma.

Comment: This does not work in localized Excel versions where the decimal separator is a comma.

Comment: Good point. I knew they would be a catch somewhere. I will leave my answer up though, people can vote it down if they wish.

Comment: Huh, `MAX(--D:D)` works for me while `MAX(D:D)` did not -  what is the difference between the two?

Comment: The decimal separator in my locale is the comma btw, and it does seem to work (both with and without `trunc`)

Comment: Actually this is getting quite interesting. The -- forces the string to be interpreted as a number (or in this case as a date since . is the dd.mm.yy separator in your locale, not the decimal separator). A string like 12.2021 will be interpreted as 01.12.2021 . Then Max will find the latest date. I'm sorry to say that the formula may appear to work with the test data in your question, but it would only do so because 01.12.2021 happens to be the latest year as well as the latest month.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work. And it is short.

```
Sub test()
    Dim max As Long
    max = [MAX(TRUNC(D:D))]
    Debug.Print max
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you seen the answer? What do you think?